# How I can put "tick mark" symbol in PDFBOX?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have to place a "tick mark" in a PDF.

I am trying to use

contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.SYMBOL, 10);

However, I can't figure out how to proceed further?

Comment: You need to know the unicode for that tick mark in that font (I don't see that there is one). Then call showText for that one. (Did you manage to output ANY text at all, e.g. from the Helvetica font?)

Comment: contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.ZAPF_DINGBATS, 8)                                 Unicode is, I got the silution "\u2714"

Comment: Great! It is what I guessed, that font has a lot of these symbols. Please answer the question yourself. (This is OK) I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Font as ZAPF_DINGBATS

```
 private fun fillTextData(parameterMetadata: ParameterMetadata, contentStream: PDPageContentStream) {
val coordinate = parameterMetadata.selectedCoordinate!!
var originalFontSize = 10.0F
val availableWidth = coordinate.width
val availableHeight = coordinate.height

val pdfTypeFont = Standard14Fonts.FontName.ZAPF_DINGBATS // This font support tick mark

contentStream.beginText()
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font(pdfTypeFont), originalFontSize)
contentStream.showText("\u2713")
contentStream.endText()
```

}